# Error when importing Gradle Project to Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I never got this error before android studio update.

I have an android project in which i want to add open cv sdk. For that i used.

> Go to File -> New -> Import Module... 
>   the Module you want to import and click Finish.

After this step i got below error, i can see module directory but it is not listed when i go for below step

> Click the (+) icon and select Module Dependency. Select the module and
>   click Ok.

I am getting this error

```
Element: class org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyFileImpl because: different providers: SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://D:/KHEMRAJ/Samples Android 2/DetectPupil1/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=16}}(61555ac4); SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://D:/KHEMRAJ/Samples Android 2/DetectPupil1/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=16}}(61da9041)
invalidated at: see attachment
com.intellij.psi.PsiInvalidElementAccessException: Element: class org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyFileImpl because: different providers: SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://D:/KHEMRAJ/Samples Android 2/DetectPupil1/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=16}}(61555ac4); SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://D:/KHEMRAJ/Samples Android 2/DetectPupil1/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=16}}(61da9041)
invalidated at: see attachment
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PsiUtilCore.ensureValid(PsiUtilCore.java:502)
    at com.intellij.pom.core.impl.PomModelImpl.startTransaction(PomModelImpl.java:346)
    at com.intellij.pom.core.impl.PomModelImpl.runTransaction(PomModelImpl.java:151)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.ChangeUtil.prepareAndRunChangeAction(ChangeUtil.java:167)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositeElement.addChild(CompositeElement.java:615)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositeElement.addChildren(CompositeElement.java:722)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.codeStyle.CodeEditUtil.addChildren(CodeEditUtil.java:67)
    at com.intellij.extapi.psi.ASTDelegatePsiElement.addInternal(ASTDelegatePsiElement.java:311)
    at com.intellij.extapi.psi.ASTDelegatePsiElement.addAfter(ASTDelegatePsiElement.java:298)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.arguments.GrArgumentListImpl.addAfter(GrArgumentListImpl.java:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.parser.GradleSettingsFile.addModule(GradleSettingsFile.java:142)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleModuleImporter.copyAndRegisterModule(GradleModuleImporter.java:295)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleModuleImporter.access$000(GradleModuleImporter.java:50)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleModuleImporter$1.run(GradleModuleImporter.java:217)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$Simple.run(WriteCommandAction.java:234)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1003)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:210)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleModuleImporter.importModules(GradleModuleImporter.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleModuleImporter.importProjects(GradleModuleImporter.java:83)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.importing.SourceToGradleModuleModel.lambda$handleFinished$0(SourceToGradleModuleModel.java:56)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1003)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.importing.SourceToGradleModuleModel.handleFinished(SourceToGradleModuleModel.java:55)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:403)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:331)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:307)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1838)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:646)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:734)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:456)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1696)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1645)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewModuleAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewModuleAction.java:71)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:237)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:195)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:346)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:646)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:734)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:456)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1696)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1645)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.lambda$show$0(SettingsDialog.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.show(SettingsDialog.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1660)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:241)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:207)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.doShowDialog(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.showDialogAndSelect(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:134)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.editors.AndroidProjectSettingsService.openModuleSettings(AndroidProjectSettingsService.java:91)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.PsiDirectoryNode.navigate(PsiDirectoryNode.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigate(OpenSourceUtil.java:53)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.BaseNavigateToSourceAction.actionPerformed(BaseNavigateToSourceAction.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:237)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:321)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:911)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:311)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:130)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:521)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:48)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:541)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:646)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: are the `include` statements present in `settings.gradle`

Comment: Of-course @Navneetヅ

Comment: include for your module also added? also try `File menu > Invalidate caches and restart`

Comment: Yes i have included in app level dependency block. that's automatically added

Comment: Google makes some things weird in updates